# React-ace - Get cursor position

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

I was checking ace editor docs & found that, `editor.getCursorPosition()` retrieves the current cursor position.

But how do I do this in react-ace.  I'm not sure, how to get the editor instance & call getCursorPosition() function over it.

I checked the react-ace documentation as well but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.  My requirement was to know which line is being edited.

I got access to the **selection** object with **onSelectionChange props**.  Then I stored selection object in a state variable & called selection.getCursor() method in onChange function.

sample code

```
      <TextEditor
        id={`editor_${index}`}
        isRequired={true}
        inputObject={inputObj}
        onSelectionChange={(selectionObj) => {
        setEditoreditorSelectionObject(selectionObj);
        }}
        onChange = {() => {
            const cursor = editorSelectionObject.getCursor();
            //do some operations with cursor
        }}
      />
```